# Why Santa Claus is said to be from "Yoda's species"?

Tags: star-wars

On [Wookieepedia's List of Yoda's species members](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Members_of_Yoda%27s_species), there is an entry for [Santa Claus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Santa_Claus).

Apart from the mention that:

> In 2006 a limited edition figurine was issued of Yoda dressed in a Santa suit with a sack of toys.

Why would Santa Claus be considered a member of Yoda's species?

Comment: It was a holiday promotion at one point and now is more or less just an easter egg. It's not really canon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just bad logic and, IMO, should be fixed.

From the [Santa Claus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Santa_Claus) entry you linked:

> Santa Claus was a festively dressed, probable member of the Rebel Alliance stationed on the cruiser Independence.
>
> A member of the same species as the Jedi Master Yoda, possibly Yoda himself, was known to have donned regalia similar to Claus's distinctive outfit on at least one occasion.
>
> In 3,963 BBY, Santa or a being dressed as him was located at Goodvalor's Little Bivoli.

They seem to be following the line of reasoning that since someone of Yoda's species was dressed as Santa at one point, and there is no directly refuting evidence, that Santa may be a member of Yoda's species.

Comment: They're also relying on the assumption that a character *appearing* to be Santa Claus actually *is* Santa Claus - the top section of the Wookieepedia article notes that this may be a fallacy.

Comment: *Running away to dress as Darth Vader so they'll write that I'm a Sith Lord on Wookiepedia*

Comment: Well, clearly 3PO is the real Santa and R2 is a reindeer. http://i.imgur.com/OC0jw.jpg